# When can the valuative criterion of universal closure be checked on complete DVRs

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, schemes

Assume that I have a morphism of nice algebraic stacks $f : X \to Y$ that I want to show is universally closed. Suppose I have checked that for every *complete* DVR $R$ with *algebraically closed* residue field $k$ and fraction field $K$ and every generic lifting
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
    \mathrm{Spec}\, K @>>> X\\
    @VV V @VV f V\\
    \mathrm{Spec}\, R @>>> Y
\end{CD}
there exists a finite separable extension $K'/K$, a valuation ring $R' \subseteq K'$ dominating $R$, and a $R'$-point of $X$ which commutes when inserted into the diagram

$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
    \mathrm{Spec}\, K' @>>> \mathrm{Spec}\, K @>>> X\\
    @VV V @VV V @VV f V\\
    \mathrm{Spec}\, R' @>>> \mathrm{Spec}\, R @>>> Y
\end{CD}

Is this enough to show properness? Can someone give a reference or sketch the reduction from the usual valuative criterion, especially the reduction to the complete case? The "finite extension of $K$ and $R$" part is handled in Stacks 0H1Y, and the "algebraically closed residue field" can be removed by passing to an unramified extension of $K$ and $R$ first and applying the stacks result (our extensions are no longer finite, but that's fine by (5)). I haven't found any references that the criterion can be checked after completion of the DVR.